# Angular 5 + materializecss Form reset

Tags: materialize, angular5

I have a form for adding new users and I am having problems with the form reset because it does not remove the valid class of materialize.

The form:

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l4 xl4">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(); newLabMember.reset()" #newLabMember="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
        <!-- New lab member form -->
        <div class="section">
          <h5>Add lab member</h5>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="user.firstname" class="validate" id="firstName" validate required>
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="user.lastname" class="validate" id="lastName" validate required>
            <label for="firstName">Last name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="validate" id="email" validate required>
            <label for="email">Member email</label>
          </div>
          <blockquote>An email will be sent to the new user with a password and further instructions.
            </blockquote>
          <div class="input-field">
            <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-1">Add new member</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

As you can see, when I submit the form I use reset() form but the class .valid from materialize still there.

Comment: same issue here, did you find some nice way ?

Comment: yes, i found an ugly solution: i named all the inputs with for example: #firstNameInput, then linked it with @ViewChild("firstNameInput") firstnameBox; and when submit i remove manually all the classes with: this.firstNameInput.nativeElement.classList.remove("valid"); hope it helps you

Comment: yeah :-) i got similar approach , watching if modal is displayed and then i  clear with jquery ....could not invest more time into it